# Domain in proof of Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}
\newcommand{\d}{\text{d}}
$$

Most statements of Euler's theorem for homogeneous functions I found restrict the domain of

- the considered function, and/or
- the homogeneity degree, and/or
- the rescaling parameter.

For example

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Euler%27s_homogeneous_function_theorem) states the theorem for *positively* homogeneous functions $f: \R^n \setminus {0} \ra \R$
- [Apostol](https://archive.org/details/calculus-tom-m.-apostol-calculus-volume-2-2nd-edition-proper-2-1975-wiley-sons-libgen.lc/Apostol%20T.%20M.%20-%20Calculus%20vol%20II%20%281967%29/page/286/mode/2up) at pag. 287 considers only positive rescaling parameters.

I don't see what goes wrong with this generality:

###### Definition

Let $k$ be an integer. A differentiable function $f: \R^n \ra \R$ is $k$-homogeneous if
$$
f(ax) = a^kf(x)
$$
for all $x \in \R^n$ and all $a \in \R \setminus {0}$.

###### Euler's Theorem

Let $k$ be an integer and let $f: \R^n \ra \R$ be a differentiable function. Then $f$ is $k$-homogeneous if and only if
$$
x \cdot \d{f}(x) = kf(x)
$$
for all $x \in \R^n$.

###### Proof

Let $f$ be $k$-homogeneous. Then for any nonzero real $a$, $f(ax) = a^k f(x)$. Differentiate with respect to $a$:
$$
\d{f}(ax) \cdot x =  ka^{k-1}f(x)
$$
In particular this must be true for $a$ = 1, so
$$
\d{f}(x) \cdot x = kf(x)
$$

Conversely, let the condition above hold; then for any real $a$, $ax \cdot \d{f}(ax) = k f (ax)$.

Define $g(a) = f(ax)$ for any fixed $x \in \R^n$. *I guess here it is actually necessary to consider $g(a) = f(ax)$ for any fixed $x \in \R^n \setminus {0}$.* Differentiate $g$ with respect to $a$, and assume $a \neq 0$:
$$
\frac{\d{}}{\d{a}}g(a) = \d{f}(ax) \cdot x = \frac{\d{f}(ax) \cdot ax}{a} = \frac{k}{a}f(ax) = \frac{k}{a}g(a)
$$
The solution of this ODE is $g(a) = g(1) a^k$, i.e. $f(ax) = a^k f(x)$ for all nonzero $a$.

---

To wrap up

- I'm not sure whether it is necessary to state the theorem excluding the origin of $\R^n$ from the domain of $f$;
- The only constraint on $a$ seems to be $a \neq 0$;
- I see no constraint on the homogeneity degree $k$, namely the theorem seems to hold for $k>0$, $k=0$ and $k<0$.

Is this correct?