# Proof of Euler's theorem for positively homogeneous functions $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\to\Bbb R$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

1. $f(x,y) = f(αx,αy)$ for all $α>0$ and $(x,y)$ distinct from $(0,0)$
2. $f$ satisfies:

$$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$$

**My attempt**:

what I tried is to do the implication go from 2) to 1). I divide by the partial derivative (I dont know if I can do this actually, I guessed than since the limit is just a value I could do it, and if that limit is equal to zero then going from 1) to 2) is trivial since $f$ is just a constant value) and obtain:

$$\frac{x}{-y} = \frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}.$$

Then, using partial derivative definition, you get that $x=-y,$ which implies that the partial derivative respect to $x$ is equal to the partial derivative respect to $y.$

From this I tried to justify 1) but I just got stuck. I think I am really far from getting the question right but I wanted to know whether what I am doing right or wrong from my reasoning.

Comment: There is a proof in [this (unanswered) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316118).

Comment: As you've written it though, the only differentiable functions that satisfy $f(x,y) = f(ax,ay)$ are constants so their derivatives would be zero.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget a $\alpha^k$ for some $k$ in the first line ?

Comment: yes, the question was written just like that. i will ask my teacher if something was wrong though.